# not able to select listbox item with key board arrow key in a windows form application

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, listboxitem

On textbox text changed event I am calling a user defined function to get item title from database and populate a list-box with returned titles. 
Now I want users to be able to press down arrow key on text box and it should select first item in list box and when user press "enter" key in list box another function should be called. I am doing this,

```
private void txtItemCode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (lstBoxItems.Items.Count != 0)
            {

                lstBoxItems.Focus();
                lstBoxItems.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Item Code");
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (lstBoxItems.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                lstBoxItems.Focus();
                lstBoxItems.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Item Code");
            }
        }
    }

    private void lstBoxItems_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {         
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            getPreviousBalance();
            getItemDetails();
            txtUnitPrice.Focus();
        }
    }
```

With this code down allow key is working as first item in list box get "highlighted" but when i press enter key in list box it is not working because the item get highlighted but it is not selected as when i press mouse click on same item and then press enter it works but with select with mouse click it is not working.
Please help

Comment: In `txtItemCode_KeyDown`, you might have to set [Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` so the keystroke doesn't propagate back to the control and take the focus back.